# Kendo device specific css

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Working in Kendo UI Mobile, is it possible to define device specific css elements.

For example to perform platform specific css for iOS and Android I use

```
.km-ios .km-view-title
{
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.km-android .km-view-title
{
    height: 50px;
    color: #000;
}
```

however how to specify between iPhone 4 and iPhone5, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI Mobile does not provide device specific classes. You can add such class  manually, based on the difference of the screen height.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating a function that adjusted the height of divs within the homepage based on window height ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually Kendo UI Mobile does add platform version CSS classes by concatenating the platform class and its major version. So, you can target iOS5 with .km-ios5 and Android 2.x with .km-android2.

There's one additional catch - iOS7 doesn't have the .km-ios class that previous iOSes have - this is due to the major redesign the platform received, so Kendo UI Mobile considers it separate.

Comment: Thanks Bundyo, this is good to know and will come in handy I'm sure, however I am looking for device specific css (ie iPhone4 vs iPhone5) not platform version specific (ie iOS6 vs iOS7)

Comment: Seems I've misunderstood then, yes - as Petyo said - we don't have those.